# Using Ruby How To Avoid Writing Extra Lines To File

Tags: ruby

The following Ruby code causes extra lines to be written, and I am trying to find out what is causing that.

My Ruby code:

```
File.delete(RAILS_ROOT + '/app/views/filer/' + @navn + ".html.erb")
filen = File.open(RAILS_ROOT + '/app/views/filer/' + @app.slug + ".html.erb", "a+")
filen.write("#{params[:app][:cod]}")
```

I have inspected the params:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="app[cod]" <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="da"> <head> <title>Ruby on Rails: Welcome aboard</title> <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
```

But when the file is created there are added new lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="da">

<head> <title>Ruby on Rails: Welcome aboard</title>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
```

When it should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="da">
<head> <title>Ruby on Rails: Welcome aboard</title>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
```

And here is an inpection with the rails inspect:

```
"cod"=>"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"da\">\r\n<head>
```

Comment: well i cant understand why new lines are getting added. but can try string.chomp method. (params[:app][:cod].chomp) and pass it to write function

Comment: Is whatever method of visualisation you are using interpreting the "\r\n" in the files as 2 new lines?

Comment: @mashit just tried it and there is still new lines added

Comment: @FrederickCheung the file is opened in a textarea and then saved. I have tried the gsub method on /r and /n. Still new lines are added.

Comment: Just forgot gsub should be "" and not ''. This worked filen.puts("#{params[:app][:cod].gsub("\n", "")}")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the gsub method to get rid of the new lines:

```
filen.puts("#{params[:app][:cod].gsub("\n", "")}")
```

Comment: originally did you use filen.puts or filen.write ? because when you use write, new line wont be added. but in case of puts, it will add a new line as a separator. so u will require gsub or other methods as you posted in your answer.

Comment: it was write. New lines where added. Then I used puts instead with gsub.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with embedded line terminators in a Posix-style block write seems to be just asking for trouble. Why not just do something portable that will always work, like ...

```
puts "how\r\nnow\r\nbrown\r\ncow".split
```

Although reaching into the string to "fix" them would also work, why not let the built-in code do it for you?

Certainly in this case, it *is* unlikely that someone will come along with a new OS and a new line-terminating scheme. (How evil would *that* be, anyway?)

But still, as a general rule and for practice: let the local library deal with anything system-dependent. Write your code to run anywhere.